# extracting jar file in jmeter

Tags: selenium, junit, jmeter

selenium Code - exported the below code and exported jar files in junit.if i open in junit request in jmeter , i'm unable to get the class file.i also checked the junit 4 check list.

```
 public class BriquesoftLoadTest {
          @Test
          public void openBrowser() {
              System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Jar\\geckodriver.exe");
              WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
              driver.get("http://google.com/");
              System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you aware of the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) plugin which provides Selenium integration?

If for some reason it doesn't play for you and you need to continue with JUnit, here is some form of the checklist:

1. Make sure that .jar with your test lives under "lib/junit" folder of your JMeter installation. You will also need to restart JMeter to pick the .jar up.
2. You will need to add Selenium libraries to JMeter classpath. Again you need to copy Selenium and other .jars to JMeter's "lib" folder and restart JMeter. The easiest way of getting Selenium libraries is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/), you can get all the necessary jars installed in a single click:

   [image: Plugins Manager Selenium]
3. Once you do it, make sure you tick `Search for JUnit 4 annotations (instead of JUnit 3)

   [image: Selenium JMeter Junit]
4. In case of any unexpected behaviour first thing you should do is to check *jmeter.log* file - in majority of cases it contains enough troubleshooting information to get to the bottom of the issue.

See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article for more information on using JUnit tests in JMeter test plans.

Comment: i know to add a normal java project to selenium,but my question how can you integrate a testNG class of a selenium project with a jmeter?

Comment: how to do a load testing using testNG framework. i also need to integrate testng framework with jmeter .i tried using junit ,i also need to do with the help of testng .can anyone help me to do the testng integration with jmeter?

Comment: Currently JMeter does not recognise TestNG tests.

Comment: oki ..How will i do a performance test in selenium testNG?without jmeter is there any possibilities to open 100 browser at a time?

Comment: Have you tried reading [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests)

Comment: yeah i read about it, but in jmeter we can able to get the performance report in both matrix and visual tree structure,if we use testNG can we able to get the exact result as compared to jmeter?

Comment: If you want JMeter **again**, you can consider [converting your TestNG Selenium test to "pure" JMeter test script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter)

Comment: my question is , shall i go for jmeter to test performance test or i can continue with testNG framework (testNG suite) to run the parallel test.Which is widely used in market. which one will give a exact reult?

Comment: Your question is about running a JUnit test in JMeter. I believe it is answered.

Comment: But i had another question ,even that i posted. can you able to get me an solution . i'm finding a tough to integrate a selenium with jmeter? Especially testNG framework to jmeter.